# Выбор последней добавленной строки из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здрасти, есть система тиккетов. Таблица для нее одна в базе.

вот такая:

```
id | pid | title | msg | time
```

Клиент создает тиккет с pid=0, на него отвечают манагеры и у всех ответов pid=ID тикету, которого создал клиент. Пример:

```
1 | 0 | тест | Мой вопрос 
2 | 1 | RE: тест| ответ на ваш вопрос1
3 | 1 | RE: тест| ответ на ваш вопрос2
4 | 1 | RE: тест| ответ на ваш вопрос3
5 | 1 | RE: тест| ответ на ваш вопрос4
6 | 1 | RE: тест| ответ на ваш вопрос5
```

Мне нужно выбрать все строки с pid=0 и последние ответы к ним. В данном случае в результате должно  быть первая строка и 6-тая

Comment: Между прочим, крутая задачка. Полчаса уже долблюсь.

Comment: Плохой дизайн. Тикет с текстом и комменты к тикету должны быть в разных таблицах. Поэтому и проблемы с запросами.

Comment: А без разницы. Одним запросом все равно через джойны делать, итого в запросе только вторая таблица поменяется. А вообще сделать поле last_answer_id и обновлять его при ответе - это да)

Comment: Как-то не грамотно так куда-то запоминать ласт_айди)))) а две таблицы самое то, но изначально такого условия не было, как в этой задаче. Поэтому таблицу так и создавал.

Comment: Ну вообще это довольно частый ход - кэш-значение. Тогда бы зато запрос выглядел "**`select * from thetable as t1 join thetable as t2 on t2.id=t1.last_answer_id where t1.pid=0;`**"

Comment: зато в 5 других местах пришлось бы делать апдейт)))

Comment: Ну в системе тикетов в принципе еще можно подумать, но например новостной портал (1-3 апдейта, 50к просмотров) это вполне оправдано) распределение нагрузки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это жесть какая-то))

```
SELECT 
  T1.id AS ticket_id,
  T1.title AS ticket_title,
  T1.msg AS ticket_msg,
  T1.user_id AS ticket_user,
  T2.id AS answer_id,
  T2.user_id AS answer_user,
  T2.manager_id AS answer_manager,
  T2.time AS answer_time
FROM thetable AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN thetable AS T2 ON (
 (T2.pid=T1.id) AND
 (T2.id=( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM thetable  WHERE pid = T1.id ) )
  )
WHERE T1.pid =0
GROUP BY T1.id
```

Советую сперва из пхпадмина тестить что ли. Будут ошибки - выдавайте сюда.

Comment: Что-то Выдало, результат не удовлетворяет))) потому что из трех тиккетов выдало только 2

Comment: К третьему есть ответ?

Comment: Нет, нету!..Не учли? Я в этом запросе ничего не понял, поэтому я его тупо скопировал без правки)))

Две записи которые выдало, ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ!!!

Comment: @Sh4dow добьете вопрос?))) очь очь нужно решение этого вопроса. У меня цел день на это ушло.


А я еще усложню задачку, после того, как решим эту))) там нужно будет добавить сортировку по двум полям)

Comment: Wohoo! Обновил, проверяйте. А сортировка, кстати, как обычно: в конец допишите **ORDER BY ticket_id** например

Comment: Фух! Здорово! Получилось! Спасибо огромное!

Кстати, время запроси сократилось в два раза, после обновления!

Comment: Пожалуйста) *Мне +1000ХР, Для себя записал: JOIN ON(условия, которые влияют на тип джойна) ... WHERE (условия, которым параллелен вид джойна).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from thetable  where pid=0
union
select t1.*
from thetable  t1
join (select id, times
from thetable 
where pid!=0
order by time desc limit 0,1) as t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

Не имея под рукой MySQL, проверил на MSSQL. Полный скрипт такой

```
set dateformat dmy  
set nocount on  
create table #t (id int, pid int, times datetime)  
insert into #t values(1, 0, '1-10-2011 12:00')  
insert into #t values(2, 1, '1-10-2011 12:30')  
insert into #t values(3, 1, '1-10-2011 12:20')  
insert into #t values(4, 0, '1-10-2011 12:21')

select * from #t where pid=0
union
select t1.*
from #t t1
join (select top 1 id, times
from #t
where pid!=0
order by times desc) as t2 on t2.id=t1.id

drop table #t
```

Ответ:

> `1   0   2011-10-01 12:00:00.000
> 2   1   2011-10-01 12:30:00.000
> 4   0   2011-10-01 12:21:00.000`

Ну и что - ответ вполне осмысленный.

Comment: Чет не пойму, как теперь в результате иметь значение полей от ответа?

и потом в таблице ж не один тикет:

select id, times

from thetable 

where pid!=0

order by time desc limit 0,1

Почему это должно вывести именно ответ текущего тиккета?

Comment: В конце объединение же "**on t2.pid=t1.id**" (это уже я исправил). Вообще ща у себя проверю.

Comment: таблица такая. id, pid, user_id, manager_id, title, msg, time

в ответе должно быть тема тиккета (title),  текст тиккета (msg), ид пользователя, который создал тикет (user_id). И в том же объекте (массиве) должно быть от последнего ответа: user_id, manager_id и time

Comment: Ну и зачем исправили, исправляйте обратно.

Comment: Т.е. мой запрос бессмысленный что ли? Обновил ответ.

Comment: <a href="http://mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html">Синтаксис JOIN</a> Mysql не поддерживает `JOIN (SELECT ...)`, только `JOIN TABLE ...`

Comment: Ну прям

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-5.0-en/sql-syntax.html#unnamed-views

Comment: Не вижу там джойна. У вас трудности с переводом "Subqueries in the FROM clause cannot be correlated subqueries, unless used within the ON clause of a JOIN operation. "? "Подзапросы в FROM не должны пересекаться друг с другом, кроме подзапросов в разделе ON оператора JOIN". Т.е. SELECT TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID IN (SELECT ...). Как видите, совсем не по теме. А с джойном селект использовать нельзя.

Comment: Я конечно далеко не Пастернак, но может стоит просто выполнить мой запрос, как я его привел?

Comment: Эм. Каюсь в документации. НО: Запрос вернул все тикеты и 1 последний ответ. Причем тупо списком, без связи.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так, запрос не проверял, но мысль надеюсь Вам понятна:

```
SELECT x.* FROM thetable x,(SELECT MAX(id) as mid,pid FROM  thetable GROUP BY pid) t
WHERE x.id != 0 AND x.id = t.mid AND x.pid = t.pid
```

Результат - строки с последними ответами + добавить еще 1 тривиальный подзапрос и получится то, что вам нужно...

Comment: Да вопрос уже был решен еще вчера. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

А проще же можно было

```
select * from table where pid = '0' order by 'id' desc
```

ну или так

```
select * from table where pid = '0' order by 'id' desc limit 10
```

Далее `echo "тема тикета .$row['title']., текст тиккета .$row['msg'], ид пользователя, который создал тикет .$row['user_id'].";`

Comment: Еслибы так просто было, не мучались бы

Comment: Вроде ему нужен конкретный pid (where pid = x) и посл ответы (desc) ,
ну может я не правильно понял вопроса, просто помочь хотел.